# Spring sso oauth2 client unable to request for access token

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, oauth-2.0

on spring boot 1.4, using @EnableOAuth2Sso for sso client and a kong third party authorization server, i'm able to receive the authorization code but unable to retrieve the access token.

the authorization code is part of the redirect url after which is there any configuration or a process for retrieving the access token?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the Authz code, you need to make a server side call(so that access token flow doesn't go through end user browser) to Authz Server for access_token, Look at [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) section of OAuth 2.0 Spec.